# Powershell ISE variable highlighter

Tags: powershell, scripting, add-on

Is there any add-ons for Powershell ISE where you can highlight any occurrence of the variable or any word? Something like Sublime Text has?

Comment: I'm not sure about Powershell ISE, but you should check out Visual Studio Code if you are developing powershell... it is awesome. https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Visual Studio Code with Powershell extensions is much better than the ISE IMO

Comment: Do I need to download the Powershell Extention or it comes out of the box?

Comment: Oh wow, it is beautiful. Thanks for the suggestions guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ISE doesn't have support for add-ons, but [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) does (and there's lots of good ones). It also has much better built-in syntax highlighting and Git support (if Git is installed). You'll need to install the PowerShell extension from the "extension marketplace" (just search for "PowerShell"). Also, Microsoft has said that they're not planning to continue maintenance of ISE, so VS Code is probably what you should be using to write PowerShell.

Comment: However, my ps script is working flawlessly in ISE and poweshell, but when I run the same script in VS Code it is stuck at the some functions and stops executing. No error thrown, the script just freezes. Any idea?

Comment: Huh. That's really weird... Are you sure you didn't somehow accidentally set a breakpoint?

Answer (score -1):

The ISE was not highlighting any keywords/syntaxes, for me the issue was with the file extension,  the PS script file extension was inadvertently set to `.ps`, when I renamed it to have `.ps1` extension, all the syntax highlighting revived.  Hope this helps others.

Comment: The Question is about variable highlighting.